# Proper auth using YouTube Data Api V3 and .net core

Tags: youtube-data-api

I was able to create and use an Api key but this does not give me access to my YouTube account videos.

The api docs have no .net code examples. From what I can gather from the docs, you can't use the api key to access your account and need to use Oauth instead. How would I do this from a desktop app?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for this? https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs at the very least it shows me nearly everything I can do with my channel as well as general search. From there u just need to find the appropriate API method in the c# library

Comment: `you can't use the api key to access your account and need to use Oauth instead` I could be wrong but I don't see anywhere in the API docs mentioning you must use Oauth, since the API Key should already hint which user you are.

Comment: @Prix Using the Api key is similar to using youtube.com as an anonymous user. You can search for videos on your channel but you won't see any private ones or be able to update anything. 

The `mine` request property on `Playlist:List` api end-point mentions it "can only be used in a properly authorized request" 

This is the doc it refers to but without any C# examples https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication

Comment: no its not the same as being an anonymous user no, not only its not, but you also have methods to upload videos to your own channel. **But even if you need oauth it does say you can use the api with oauth as well**, so I dont see the issue, there is also examples in the docs https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert#.net

Comment: @Prix Thank you! This does help put me in the correct direction. I just know I've tested with using an apikey only and when using properties like `Mine` it will say you're not authorized to use it. I'll dive into this doc more shortly but do you happen to know where `client_secrets.json` is being generated from?

Comment: You get the client_secrets from google console page from your app